# How would I include a third party image gallery on my Cornerstone-based theme?

Tags: jquery, node.js, webpack, bigcommerce

I'm requested to add a new image gallery for our products page. I've found a few that I like, and I got really close to adding one using the advanced [non-npm method](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/js-non-npm). I tried [Galleria](https://galleria.io/), [UniteGallery](http://unitegallery.net/), and [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html). Is there any way someone can walk me through installing it on Cornerstone (v1.5.3)? Cornerstone uses WebPack 1.14.

Comment: Can you expand on what hasn't worked about what you've tried?

Comment: I followed the instructions on [the advanced non-npm method](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/js-non-npm) for both Galleria and UniteGallery by putting them in a vendor folder and importing on the product.js file. Galleria came up with a "jQuery isn't found" error, while UniteGallery actually loaded but displayed all wrong. I loaded PhotoSwipe through the [basic npm method](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/js-npm-basic) with [npm ECMAScript instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.photoswipe) and got `SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.